# Remove cycle by duplicating nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I have a problem where I want to convert a graph to actual code, where nodes represent an operation and edges represent dependencies. I can directly convert a linear graph into a code, where one operation can come after the other. The challenge is converting it in presence of a cycle. I am planning to do it by replicating n-1 nodes in an n-node cycle.

`e.g. You have a cycle A->B->C->A. To remove the cycle I am going to convert it into a linear form while maintaining dependency by duplicating nodes i.e. A1->B1->C->A2->B2`

So some of my questions are that

Is there any other graph theory heuristic which handles such problem?

Is there any other way to linearize the graph while satisfying the edge dependencies?

Comment: In your example after the duplication the rightmost node `B2` appears to have unsatisfied `C` dependency. Is it ok for your case? If yes, can you be more specific about how do these "dependencies" work in your case. Probably with some real examples of the nodes and dependencies between them.

Comment: You lost a B2->C1 dependency there. How are you going to represent that? You will never finish writing dependencies when you create new instances of your nodes.

Comment: I think I understand that you need to do B after you do A, then you need to do C after you do B, and (sometimes) you need to do A after you do C. Is that it? And by "a code", do you mean software or something else?

Comment: @Erick G. Hagstrom Yes thats it. The nodes can be software, a function etc.

Comment: @bardao,@Aivean, the logic explained by  Erick G. Hagstrom is what I am trying to say.

Comment: Is it also true that, when you need to do A after C, you know that you only have to do it once? Or that you know in advance how many times you need to do it? Or just that there's some condition that needs to be satisfied? I'm concerned that the number of iterations around the cycle might not be known in advance.